# Open MP4 video on smartphones in full screen mode via Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have a video in MP4 format sitting in a directory on my website. On a smartphone, when someone clicks a link, I want to open the video in full screen mode, while leaving the website exactly where it was before. So that after the video plays, the user can close it, and the website is still there. What is the best way to do this?

I already have a separate link for smartphones. I am handling the video in a different way on other types of devices.

Comment: I guess you could include the mp4 in a video element and then call [requestFullscreen()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen) on it.

Comment: My idea was to simply do this (which seems to work), but I wasn't sure if there was a better way: window.open('/video/hero-mobile.mp4');